# Find elements meeting any of a number of criteria

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the indices of elements in a vector that correspond to another vector, preferably without using loops. For example, my input might be:

```
DJiSet = [5 7 8];                   % elements of which I need the indices
JiSet = [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 20];   % vector to search
```

The output here would be:

```
[3 5 6]
```

The fastest I've come up with so far is this:

```
Output = find(ismember(JiSet,DJiSet));
```

However I have a feeling this could be done faster, especially since I thought the `find` command is rather slow.

Things to note:

- The values in `DJiSet` are guaranteed to all be present in `JiSet`
- `JiSet` is always sorted in ascending order, without repeated entries
- The vector `DJiSet` is not guaranteed to be found contiguously in `JiSet`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can avoid `find` by reversing the places of `DJiSet` and `JiSet` inside `ismember` and then use the second output that gives us the matching indices  -

```
[~,out] = ismember(DJiSet,JiSet)
```

---

**Approach #2**

Loopy approach catering to the specific conditions set in the question could be tried out, not sure if this will be more efficient though -

```
intv_idx = zeros(1,numel(DJiSet));
intv_idx(1) = find(JiSet==DJiSet(1),1);
start = intv_idx(1)+1;
for k = 2:numel(DJiSet)
    idx = find(JiSet(start:end)==DJiSet(k),1);
    start = idx+start;
    intv_idx(k) = idx;
end
out = cumsum(intv_idx);
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds haha +1

Comment: You? Writing a `for` loop? What happened?

Comment: @Adriaan One of those dark days I guess :)

Answer (score 5):

[Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29101879/2586922) is the way to go. But in case you want to do it more manually:

```
[~, Output] = max(bsxfun(@eq, DJiSet(:).', JiSet(:)), [], 1);
```

This finds the *first* occurrence if there are more than one.

If the values in `DJiSet` were *not guaranteed* to be present in `JiSet`, you could use a small modification:

```
[val, Output] = max(bsxfun(@eq, DJiSet(:).', JiSet(:))); %'
Output(~val) = 0; %// 0 indicates "not found"
```

Answer (score 5):

**For small datasets**, it seems my original approach was faster than both the `ismember` solution proposed by Divakar and the `intersect` solution proposed by qmeeeeeee, but all three get beaten by Luis Mendo's solution using good old `bsxfun`. See below code, which times each approach:

```
function somescript()

IsmemberTime = timeit(@membersol)
IntersectTime = timeit(@intersectsol)
FindTime = timeit(@naivesol)
BsxTime = timeit(@bsxfunsol)

    function membersol()
        rng(1)
        set = randi(30,[1000 15]);             % generate 1000 vectors of length 15, containing random integers
        for i=1:1000
            [~,out] = ismember(set(i,1:5),set(i,6:end));      % first 5 random integers are the values to be found in the remainder of the vector
        end

    end

    function intersectsol()
        rng(1)
        set = randi(30,[1000 15]);
        for i=1:1000
            [~,~,Output] = intersect(set(i,1:5),set(i,6:end));
        end
    end

    function naivesol()
        rng(1)
        set = randi(30,[1000 15]);
        for i=1:1000
            Output = find(ismember(set(i,6:end),set(i,1:5)));
        end
    end

    function bsxfunsol()
        rng(1)
        set = randi(30,[1000 15]);
        for i=1:1000
            [~, Output] = max(bsxfun(@eq, set(i,1:5).', set(i,6:end)), [], 1);
        end
    end
end
```

Which on my machine (running R2014b) returns the following timings:

```
IsmemberTime =

    0.1101


IntersectTime =

    0.2008


FindTime =

    0.0698


BsxTime =

    0.0218
```

This suggests that, for small data sets at least, using `find` and `ismember` on the inverted order of vectors is actually faster than using `ismember` alone. Since there is also some fixed overhead for all methods from the generation of the datasets `set` that are used to test with, the difference seems to be pretty big. More thorough tests can ben found in the comments below.

Comment: Nice benchmarking. Did you try my solution? It seems to be faster (see updated benchmarking code [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/38j9dxV5bmvtfKqyXdWRwuW)). Also, Divakar has provided a new approach in his answer

Comment: @LuisMendo Nope, the new approach seems slower on some quick tests!

Comment: @LuisMendo I meant my new approach was slower :) Well, here's another way to do the benchmarking covering all listed approaches excluding my new approach which is slow at times, unless OP might be dealing with a very small `DJiSet` - http://ideone.com/0LO47t. Seems like original approach is best suited here!

Comment: [This one](http://ideone.com/6YnRq6) covers all approaches. [This one](http://ideone.com/VnSTlE) with larger datasizes covers all except `bsxfun` as it was going out-of-memory for this case. The proposed `[~,out] = ismember(DJiSet,JiSet)` doesn't look bad after all! For small datasizes, `bsxfun` might be a good choice though!

Comment: Just did another run with the same criteria for creating random inputs and seems like `bsxfun` is doing pretty good across a wide range of datasizes, unless of course if you are dealing with extremely huge datasizes, in which case `ismember` seems like a better option.

Comment: @Divakar @LuisMendo Thanks for the intensive testing! In my case, both `DJiSet` and `JiSet` tend to be very short vectors (usually less than 10 entries). The code is used for a distributed robotics computation, where `JiSet` determines the local neighborhood of robot `i` and `DJiSet` are the robots on the 'border' of this set. Since I have to run this code for each robot `i` and about 6e5 iterations, even a small gain was pretty worthwhile. For such short vectors, `bsxfun` indeed seems fastest. I'll update my answer accordingly, including the added timing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could try intersect? It is suppose to be a lot faster:

```
[Intersect,indDJiSet,indJiSet] = intersect(DJiSet,JiSet)
```

The ordering does not matter, as long as the element exist in both list, the ind elements gives the index.