# Speeding up ''ismember'' in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab

I'm using the Matlab build in command ''ismember'' to see whether a certain data set is within a larger dataset. The purpose of the piece of code is to remove any multiples of the [0  0] row from the larger data set shown below:

To do achieve this, I am using the following piece of code:

```
[Lia,locB] = ismember([0 0; 0 0],AFdata,'rows');
if sum(Lia) > 1 
AFdata(locB(1):locB(end-1),:) = [];
```

end

```
AFdata = [
1.0000   -0.0114
0.9975   -0.0098
0.9951   -0.0084
0.9928   -0.0074
0.9903   -0.0066
0.9804   -0.0042
0.9705   -0.0018
0.9606    0.0004
0.9507    0.0025
0.9408    0.0045
0.9309    0.0063
0.9210    0.0082
0.9111    0.0100
0.9012    0.0118
0.8913    0.0135
0.8814    0.0152
0.8715    0.0167
0.8616    0.0183
0.8517    0.0199
0.8418    0.0214
0.8318    0.0229
0.8219    0.0243
0.8120    0.0256
0.8021    0.0269
0.7922    0.0282
0.7823    0.0294
0.7724    0.0306
0.7625    0.0318
0.7526    0.0329
0.7427    0.0340
0.7328    0.0350
0.7229    0.0359
0.7130    0.0368
0.7031    0.0377
0.6932    0.0385
0.6833    0.0393
0.6734    0.0401
0.6635    0.0408
0.6536    0.0415
0.6437    0.0422
0.6338    0.0428
0.6239    0.0434
0.6140    0.0439
0.6041    0.0444
0.5942    0.0449
0.5843    0.0454
0.5744    0.0458
0.5645    0.0461
0.5546    0.0465
0.5447    0.0469
0.5348    0.0472
0.5249    0.0475
0.5150    0.0478
0.5051    0.0481
0.4951    0.0483
0.4852    0.0485
0.4753    0.0487
0.4654    0.0489
0.4555    0.0491
0.4456    0.0492
0.4357    0.0493
0.4258    0.0494
0.4159    0.0495
0.4060    0.0495
0.3961    0.0495
0.3862    0.0495
0.3763    0.0495
0.3664    0.0494
0.3565    0.0493
0.3466    0.0492
0.3367    0.0491
0.3268    0.0490
0.3169    0.0488
0.3070    0.0486
0.2971    0.0484
0.2872    0.0482
0.2773    0.0479
0.2674    0.0476
0.2575    0.0473
0.2476    0.0469
0.2377    0.0465
0.2278    0.0461
0.2179    0.0457
0.2080    0.0452
0.1981    0.0447
0.1882    0.0441
0.1783    0.0435
0.1684    0.0428
0.1584    0.0421
0.1485    0.0413
0.1386    0.0404
0.1287    0.0395
0.1188    0.0385
0.1089    0.0374
0.0990    0.0363
0.0891    0.0352
0.0792    0.0338
0.0693    0.0323
0.0594    0.0306
0.0495    0.0287
0.0396    0.0265
0.0297    0.0239
0.0198    0.0204
0.0099    0.0153
0.0050    0.0115
0.0020    0.0075
     0         0
     0         0
0.0020   -0.0075
0.0050   -0.0115
0.0099   -0.0153
0.0198   -0.0204
0.0297   -0.0239
0.0396   -0.0265
0.0495   -0.0287
0.0594   -0.0306
0.0693   -0.0323
0.0792   -0.0338
0.0891   -0.0352
0.0990   -0.0363
0.1089   -0.0375
0.1188   -0.0386
0.1287   -0.0396
0.1386   -0.0405
0.1485   -0.0414
0.1584   -0.0422
0.1684   -0.0429
0.1783   -0.0436
0.1882   -0.0442
0.1981   -0.0448
0.2080   -0.0454
0.2179   -0.0459
0.2278   -0.0463
0.2377   -0.0467
0.2476   -0.0471
0.2575   -0.0475
0.2674   -0.0478
0.2773   -0.0481
0.2872   -0.0484
0.2971   -0.0486
0.3070   -0.0488
0.3169   -0.0490
0.3268   -0.0491
0.3367   -0.0492
0.3466   -0.0493
0.3565   -0.0493
0.3664   -0.0493
0.3763   -0.0493
0.3862   -0.0492
0.3961   -0.0491
0.4060   -0.0490
0.4159   -0.0488
0.4258   -0.0486
0.4357   -0.0484
0.4456   -0.0481
0.4555   -0.0478
0.4654   -0.0474
0.4753   -0.0470
0.4852   -0.0465
0.4951   -0.0460
0.5051   -0.0455
0.5150   -0.0449
0.5249   -0.0442
0.5348   -0.0435
0.5447   -0.0427
0.5546   -0.0418
0.5645   -0.0408
0.5744   -0.0397
0.5843   -0.0386
0.5942   -0.0374
0.6041   -0.0362
0.6140   -0.0350
0.6239   -0.0337
0.6338   -0.0324
0.6437   -0.0310
0.6536   -0.0296
0.6635   -0.0281
0.6734   -0.0266
0.6833   -0.0252
0.6932   -0.0236
0.7031   -0.0220
0.7130   -0.0204
0.7229   -0.0188
0.7328   -0.0172
0.7427   -0.0156
0.7526   -0.0141
0.7625   -0.0125
0.7724   -0.0110
0.7823   -0.0095
0.7922   -0.0080
0.8021   -0.0067
0.8120   -0.0055
0.8219   -0.0045
0.8318   -0.0035
0.8418   -0.0026
0.8517   -0.0018
0.8616   -0.0012
0.8715   -0.0007
0.8814   -0.0004
0.8913   -0.0003
0.9012   -0.0004
0.9111   -0.0007
0.9210   -0.0012
0.9309   -0.0020
0.9408   -0.0030
0.9507   -0.0042
0.9606   -0.0055
0.9705   -0.0072
0.9804   -0.0092
0.9903   -0.0115
0.9928   -0.0119
0.9951   -0.0121
0.9975   -0.0119
1.0000   -0.0114]
```

However, this piece of code is executed for multiple datasets and numerous iterations which makes this a slows piece of code.

Is there any alternative to using ''ismember''? Or a quicker way to do this. Unfortunately I am not good with programing.

Comment: I would suggest reading this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101796/find-elements-meeting-any-of-a-number-of-criteria  and also, please avoid posting huge datasets, a few simple lines should make the point...

Comment: Why `[0,0;0,0]` instead of just `[0,0]`?

Comment: How about `AFdata(AFdata(:,1)~=0 | AFdata(:,2)~=0,:)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a minor improvement of [obchardon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34768704/2732801). There is no need to transpose the data set, instead use the dimension argument for `sum` or `all`. `find` is unnecessary, use logical indexing instead. Using `all` instead of `sum` makes the comparison unnecessary.

```
index =all(AFdata==0,2);
AFdata(index,:) = [];
```

Comment: Thank's, in fact i'm using `find` in order to avoid to write a big array. But i don't know if it's faster or not.

Comment: @obchardon: The big array is created in both cases, in your case it is the input argument for `find`.

Answer (score 10):

If you use logical indexing it will be faster.

```
%create index
index = sum(AFdata' == 0)==2;
%clean AFdata
AFdata(index,:) = [];
```

Comment: Very nice. You can avoid the transpose in your `sum` call and use the two input version which allows you to specify what dimension you want to sum over. In your case you want to choose 2 as the dimension as you're summing over the columns for each row.